# How to use "use strict" without modifying the scope of my utilities objects?

Tags: javascript, scope, use-strict

I'm using several global utilities objects such as:

```js
var StringUtils = {
    // ...
    equalsIgnoreCase: function(string1, string2) {
        return string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
    }
    // ...
};
```

How to use `"use strict"` in this case? I tried the following way:

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var StringUtils = {
        // ...
        equalsIgnoreCase: function(string1, string2) {
            return string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
        }
        // ...
    };

})();
```

But as you can imagine, `StringUtils` is not available anymore outside its scope.

Comment: Why are you wrapping StringUtils in IIFE?

Comment: @Satpal Because I thought that was the proper syntax to use "use strict". Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: If it's global anyway, why not use an IIFE and set it to `window.StringUtils = { ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely when you define the object in a IIFE then it will be local to that IIFE.

There are two options

**1)** Say just like bellow,

```
"use strict";
var StringUtils = {
   equalsIgnoreCase: function(string1, string2) {
       return string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
   }
};
```

OR

**2)** define like bellow if you want to use `IIFE`

```
window.StringUtils = {};
```

If you are using `nodejs` this will be

```
global.StringUtils = {};
```

Comment: What about code in the global scope which is non-strict?

Comment: @RGraham sorry I didn't get you, what do you mean.

Comment: Say you're using an external library which is also using global functions and they are not strict - this may cause them to throw an error. This is correct, it's just a pitfall for 3rd party code.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I thought that if I put "use strict" at the beginning of a JS file, it would have enable the mode for any other included file... But after some tries, I noticed that it only enables the mode for the said file. That is to say, your first solution suits my needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your options are sort of limited due to how the EMCAScript5 says to implement it.

You can go through all function blocks except those that you want global and add 'use strict'. This can be tedious but ensures only the blocks of code you desire are strict. Though this will throw 'errors' when using JS lint

You can divide the code into different files, and specify in each file which will be strict, and which will not be

And lastly you can put all your 'global' functions at the top of the script, and then below them, add the 'use strict' statement; anything below it will be strict.

All 3 of the methods allow you to access the non-strict objects from within the strict blocks.

As far as your block of code is concerned, its recommened to wrap the entirety of your js file in a function; this helps with backwards compatibility while enforcing use strict throughout the whole file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // window.StringUtils = { 
    // GLOBAL.StringUtils = {
    var StringUtils = {
        // ...
        equalsIgnoreCase: function(string1, string2) {
            return string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
        }
        // ...
    };

    // add the rest of your code here
}());
```